# what is wrong with my html code?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I am new to html.  I have been debugging my code for the past 5 hours and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it.  I reference a package that only has 1 method, which is get_country.  The link to the packages I use are here.  https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader and https://github.com/totemstech/country-reverse-geocoding

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function a() {
        var lineReader = require('line-reader');
        lineReader.eachLine(‘Location.txt', function(line, last) {
          var b= line.split(“,”,2)
          var lat= parseInt(b[0])
          var lng= parseInt(b[1])
          var crg = require('country-reverse-geocoding').country_reverse_geocoding();
          var country = crg.get_country(lat, lng);
          console.log(country.name); // 
          if (/* done */) {
            return false; // stop reading
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick=“a()>Click run reverse geocoder</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any chance it is the quotes themselves? I see one answer found your missing quote, but your double-quotes around the `line.split` look to be not a standard double quote - perhaps converting to just single quotes would help.

Comment: Now I get an error that says Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not definedhii.html:27 onclick  Do you know what might cause that?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a closing quote, you have:

```
<button type="button" onclick=“a()>Click run reverse geocoder</button>
```

and it should be:

```
<button type="button" onclick="a()">Click run reverse geocoder</button>
```

Comment: The opening quote is a curly quote, it should be a normal double quote.

Comment: Nice catch, fixing that

Comment: I ran that and now I get an error that says <button type="button" onclick=“a()”>Click run reverse geocoder</button> has an unexpected token illegal error, do you know what might be a possible fix?

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned, you're using ” quotes when instead you should be using ". You shouldn't be using the curly quotes

Comment: Thanks :) It took me a couple of glances to see that.  Now I get an error that says   Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not definedhii.html:27 onclick

Comment: It's because you need to store the function as a variable. Instead of function a() on line 4, you should do var a = function()

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the missing quote in the other answer, you have a few quotes that are not standard or double quotes. Here are the ones that a JS parser found:

- `lineReader.eachLine(‘Location.txt...` - The single quote before `Location` is not a single quote
- `var b= line.split(“,”` - These are not really double quotes - perhaps convert to single quotes or use actual double quotes

Additionally, after your closing brace to the function, you have some extra closing braces and parenthesis.

- `);` - The parenthesis and semicolon
- `}` - The last bracket

Hope this helps

Comment: I think there are no extra parentheses or brackets, the indentation is just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

- in javascript or in jQuery try to use `""` or `''` not that curely `“”` quotes
- and its `input` element in html having attribute `type` or use `button` element instead and remove type attribute. hope it would work now

  `<html>
     <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function a()
    {
    var lineReader = require('line-reader');
    lineReader.eachLine('Location.txt', function(line, last) {
    var b= line.split(',',2);
    var lat= parseInt(b[0]);
    var lng= parseInt(b[1]);
    var crg = require('country-reverse-geocoding').country_reverse_geocoding();
     var country = crg.get_country(lat, lng);
    console.log(country.name); // 
     if (/* done */) {
     return false; // stop reading
     }
    });
     }
   </script>
    </head>
   <body>
   <input type="button" onclick='a()'>Click run reverse geocoder</button>
   </body>
   </html>`

***EDIT***:
sorry IDK why the formating of code it not being applied here.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error:

```
onclick="a()" - Missing closing quotes.
```